# I want to add another action route to a resource route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the default generated route `resources :items` How do I add another route in addtion to new, edit, delete that works in the context of the object. 
I want to add 
`items/<id>/addMoney` route to respond to items#addMoney action.

How can I do this in rails? (rails 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match "/items/:id/addMoney" => "items#addMoney", via: :post
```

Assuming its a post.

Edit:

put it after the `resource :items`

or you can try this:

```
resources :items do
  get 'addMoney', on: :member
end
```

you can use `get, patch, put, post, or delete`.

Comment: isn't there something you put inside resource:items do ... end something. route. I read somewhere about nesting comments inside posts(for a blog) a long time ago

Comment: I edited the post, i think its that what you want. Also you can find much more info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html